# Conditional instantiation of class in nested classes

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Below is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
public class Map{
   int id;
   int type;
   List<Points>;
  }

public class Points{
  int xpos;
  int ypos;
  int id;
  //Building bg; or Parking pg;
}

public Building{}
public Parking{}
```

Now according to the type attribute in Map class I need to add either Building or Parking class object into Points Class.
Eg: If type == 1 then add Building to Points else if type == 2 add Parking to Points.

Could anyone please help me with this ?

Comment: What have you tried and what do you mean by *add either Building or Parking class object into points class* - there is no list to add items to

Comment: The "conditional" aspect needs explanation too - conditional on *what*?

Comment: I have edited the question a bit... Now according to the type in Map. I need to create Building Object or Parking Object in Points. Can I achieve that ?

Comment: Well you can't *declare variables* conditionally. The `Points` type either contains a `bg` variable or it doesn't. It can't "sometimes" contain it. You could create subclasses of `Points` of course. It's still unclear to me what you're trying to achieve, to be honest.

Comment: Exposing member X in a class Y indicates a has-a relation from Y to X. Does a point "have a" building, or is it actually the other way around? If the former, look into inheritance and think of a generalized base class, such as "PointOfInterest", from which Building and Parking inherit.

Comment: Yes Points has-a building. Its more like Points is-a building or Points is-a Parking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do it, is to make both `Building` and `Parking` inherit from `Point` (I'd recommend a better name by the way, maybe `Location`).

```
public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; }
}

public class Building : Location
{
    public int Stories { get; }
}

public class Parking: Location
{
    public int Capacity { get; }
}
```

And now, your `List<Location>` inside `Map` can handle both buildings and parkings:

```
locations.Add(someBuilding);
locations.Add(someParking);
```

Another option is to use interfaces: `interface ILocation` that will be implemented by `Building` and `Parking` and a `List<ILocation>` in `Map`.

When to use one or another depends on what the commonality between the different types really is:

- Inheritance: A derived type *is* a base class, A *dog* is an *animal*.
- Interfaces: A type implementing an interface *behaves* like the interface. An `int` *behaves* like an `IEquatable<int>`, a `string` too. Is there anything in common between `string` and `int` besides this behavior?

Comment: Inheriting means "is-a". Is a building a point? We don't know what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @CodeCaster OP mentioned it actually 3 minutes before this answer.

Comment: Yes Building will be the Point